# header(Location: ...) Как перенаправить на конкретную статью?

Tags: php, html, header, комментарии, location

Пишу комментарии для статей. У каждой статьи, есть свой id(id_n). По нему в ленте осуществляется переход на отдельную статью.
У каждой статьи есть форма с комментариями, в базу они добавляются, с этим проблем нет. Единственная проблема с перенаправлением обратно к этой же статье.
Собственно сам код статьи:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "citygram");
  if (!$_SESSION['user']) {
    header('Location: news_lenta.php');
}
  if($connection == false) {
    echo "Error!";
    echo mysqli_connect_errno();
    exit();
  }
  $page = $_GET['id_n'];
  $query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM news WHERE id_n='$page'");
?>
```

Сама форма с комментариями:

```
    <form action="vendor/comments.php" method="POST">
    <label for="">Комментарии</label>
    <input name="login" type="text" class="none" value="<?=$_SESSION['user']['login']?>">
    <textarea name="comm" cols="150" rows="8"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
    </form>
```

Код comments.php:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    require_once 'connect.php';
    $page = $_GET['id_n'];
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM news WHERE id_n='$page'");
     $login = $_POST['login'];
    $descr = $_POST['comm'];
    mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO `comments` (`id`,`login`, `descr`) VALUES (NULL,'$login', '$descr');");
    header("Location: content_article.php?=$page");
 ?>
```

То, что сейчас написано в header не работает. Прошу помочь

Comment: что значит "не работает"?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в Location: задать абсолютный путь, и поправьте GET параметры к правильному виду(значение параметра после равно вижу, а имя параметра пропало)

Comment: К сожалению не получается, возможно я не так пишу:
$path = "content_article.php?id_n=$page";
header("Location: $path);

Comment: Абсолютный путь в виде 
`header("Location: http://mysite.ru?param=value");`

Comment: Еще нужно убедиться, что до передачи header браузеру ещё ничего не передавалось в том числе и в файле который вы в require_once 'connect.php'; запрашиваете. Подробнее можете прочесть в документации: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php 

И пробел в строке перед $login = $_POST['login']; я бы убрал =)